# Problema al crear una entidad con clave foranea con EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Tengo un problema al intentar insertar una entidad que tiene claves foráneas en SqlServer utilizando EntityFramework Core.

Las tablas de la bbdd son estas:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pais](
    [PaisId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NomPais] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Pais] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PaisId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ComunidadAutonoma](
    [ComunidadAutonomaId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NomComunidad] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ComunidadAutonoma] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ComunidadAutonomaId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Provincia](
    [ProvinciaId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NomProvincia] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ComunidadAutonomaId] [int] NULL,
    [PaisId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Provincia] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProvinciaId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Provincia]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Provincia_ComunidadAutonoma_ComunidadAutonomaId] FOREIGN KEY([ComunidadAutonomaId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ComunidadAutonoma] ([ComunidadAutonomaId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Provincia] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Provincia_ComunidadAutonoma_ComunidadAutonomaId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Provincia]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Provincia_Pais_PaisId] FOREIGN KEY([PaisId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Pais] ([PaisId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Provincia] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Provincia_Pais_PaisId]
GO
```

Las clases del modelo son estas:

```
   [Table("Provincia")]
   public class Provincia
   {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      [Column("ProvinciaId")]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "La longitud máxima del campo es de 50")]
      public string NomProvincia { get; set; }

      public ComunidadAutonoma ComunidadAutonoma { get; set; }
      public Pais Pais { get; set; }
   }

    [Table("ComunidadAutonoma")]
   public class ComunidadAutonoma
   {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      [Column("ComunidadAutonomaId")]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "La longitud máxima del campo es de 50")]
      public string NomComunidad { get; set; }
   }

    [Table("Pais")]
   public class Pais
   {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      [Column("PaisId")]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "La longitud máxima del campo es de 50")]
      public string NomPais { get; set; }
   }
```

El código para crear la provincia básicamente es algo así:

```
var provincia = mapper.Map<Provincia>(parametro);

if (parametro.paisId != null)
{
   provincia.pais = repo.GetPais(parametro.paisId);
}

repo.CreateProvincia(provincia);
repo.SaveChanges();
```

Al intentar hacer el insert, el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
InnerException  {"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Pais' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}    System.Exception {Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}
```

Como se puede observar, una provincia puede tener, o no, comunidad autónoma y/o país.

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo tendría que hacer para poder hacer este insert?

*(No hagáis caso de todo esto que puedo poner aquí, pero al intentar publicar la pregunta, me da un error diciendo "Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código: por favor, añade más detalles", así que me he puesto a escribir este rollo para ver si me deja publicarla.
Realmente no entiendo esto).*

Comment: Veo que el error te dice que no tenes que pasarle explicitamente el valor en la tabla Pais, te fijaste que le estas pasando antes de hacer el insert? quizas debes mandarle null el id.

Comment: Pero el país ya existe. Lo que hago es añadir una nueva provincia a un país existente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

Simplemente era cuestión de definir una foreign key nullable.

```
   [Table("Provincia")]
   public class Provincia
   {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      [Column("ProvinciaId")]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "La longitud máxima del campo es de 50")]
      public string NomProvincia { get; set; }

      public int? comAutId {get; set}
      [ForeignKey("comAutId")]
      public ComunidadAutonoma ComunidadAutonoma { get; set; }
      public int? paisId {get; set}
      [ForeignKey("paisId")]
      public Pais Pais { get; set; }
   }
```

Lo dejo puesto aquí por si le es de utilidad a alguien.